# Animación de series de tiempo con datos categóricos en levelplot

Tags: r

Tengo una serie de tiempo de varios mapas raster, los cuales tienen tres valores (1, 2 y 3). Realice una animación de los mapas en levelplot en un ciclo [i] usando valores discretos en tres categorías ("Nubes","Sin nieve","Nieve"). Sin embargo, algunas de las imágenes no poseen los tres valores y al plotear me da un error por que el numero de variables y columnas no coinciden. Hay alguna manera de conservar la leyenda de tres valores y que la animación funcione para toda la serie de tiempo?.

```
library(raster)
library(xts)
library(animation)
library(rasterVis)

mypath<-"C:/Espacial"
myras<-list.files(path=mypath,pattern = glob2rx("*.tif$"), 
                    full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
name<-substr(myras,25,31)

r<-read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
date <- xts(r$Fecha, as.Date(r$Fecha, "%d-%m-%Y"))

library(animation)
# Sys.getenv("PATH", "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8")
ani.options(convert = 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\\convert.exe')

saveGIF({
  for(i in c(1:36)){
r<-raster(myras[[i]])
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$class <- c("Nubes","Sin nieve","Nieve")
levels(r) <- rat
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("cadetblue1", "burlywood4", "white"))
    l <- levelplot(r, att='class',margin=F, xlab="X",col.regions=cols,ylab="Y",
         main="Title",sub=date[[i]])
    plot(l)
  }
}, interval=0.1, movie.name="animation.gif")

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "class", value = c("Nubes", "Sin nieve",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "class", value = c("Nubes", "Sin nieve",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2
```

Comment: Dos comentarios: **1** El código que estás usando ¿funciona y da el resultado esperado sí le pasas **solamente** las imágenes que tienen los tres valores?

Comment: **2.** Por lo que se ve en el código y sin poder testearlo el problema es que el largo de `rat$class` no coincide con un data.frame que crea `levelplot` usando `att =`.  Podrías probar un `ifelse()` en `rat$class <- c(...)` para ubicar sólo los atributos que aplican en cada caso. Es decir, que si la imagen posee sólo dos valores entonces `rat$class` tenga los dos valores que coinciden. ¿Tienes forma de saber de antemano cuales imágenes poseen los tres valores y/o qué valores tiene cada una?

Comment: Así es, cuando corro imágenes sin problemas me plotea los tres valores con cada color asociado. Pero en algunas imágenes, no se encuentra el valor 3 o clase "Nieve" y me produce el error. No se como saber a priori por que es una serie de tiempo extensa. Me gustaría que si solo hay dos clases en un raster igual me plotee los colores y nombres de sus clases asociadas restantes sin interferir el ciclo de la animación de los que tienen todos los valores.

Comment: No se me ocurre como podrías hacerlo sin poder definir previamente las clases "correctas" para cada imagen  y pasar el error de diferencia de largos. ¿Seguro que no puedes consultar los atributos previamente? No digo "a mano", sino en el mismo script. No entiendo bien tu código y no tengo datos para testear, pero por lo que veo `length(levels(r)[[1]])` debería darte el largo de ese vector. De hecho podrías hacer algo como  `rat$class <- c("Nubes","Sin nieve","Nieve")[1:length(levels(r)[[1]]`, es decir, si tiene largo 2 sólo los dos primeros atributos. Ahí nos cuentas...